# How to show that $\ln{x}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> How do I show that $\displaystyle\ln{x}=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1},\ x>0$?

I have tried using Mclaurin series of $\ln(1+x)$ and replacing $x$ with $\dfrac{x-1}{x+1}$ in it but that didn't worked.

Comment: Try the series for $\arctan$ instead

Comment: Simply differentiate both sides and verify.

Comment: [Does this help?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r4K4GOAmKa8)

Answer (score 3):

Render

$\ln(1+y)=y-(y^2/2)+(y^3/3)-...$

$\ln(1-y)=-y-(y^2/2)-(y^3/3)-...$

Subtract, recognizing that the left side is $\ln[(1+y)/(1-y)]$. Thus put in

$x=(1+y)/(1-y)$

$\color{blue}{\ln(x)=2y+(2y^3/3)+...}$

and algebraically arrange this to give

$y=(x-1)/(x+1),$

which can be put into the right side of the blue equation above.

Comment: +1. BTW the series is useful for calculating $\ln n$ for small $n\in\Bbb N$. E.g. if $x\in\{4/3,9/8\}$ then $(x-1)/(x+1)\in\{1/7,1/17\},$ and we obtain $\ln 2$ and $\ln 3$ after calculating $\ln  4/3$ and $\ln 9/8.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thus series actually converges for all positive $x$ (and all complex arguments in the right half-plane), and converges faster for a given argument between $0$ and $2$ than the simple Taylor series.

Comment: Yes. When I was young and computers were bigger than cars and people used books of log tables, I saw this series in a book. After computing logs of many small primes, you are well prepared to compile a book of logs.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify the expression inside the sum using an integral of a much more elementary function in the following way:

\begin{align*}
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{2n+1}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2n+1}&=
2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}y^{2n}\,\mathrm dy=
2\int_0^{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}y^{2n}\,\mathrm dy=
2\int_0^{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\frac{\mathrm dy}{1-y^2}\\[10pt]
&=\left.\ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)\right|_{y=0}^{y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}}=\ln x
\end{align*}